# json_normalize- Nested dictionary to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Need help on the below nested dictionary and I want to convert this to a pandas Data Frame

My JSON have the following instance of CPU data and comes with random occurrence:

```
Instance1 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.03}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.37}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 58.84},, 'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

Instance2 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 55.45}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 54.16}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-06 07:50:00.000000', 'value': 50.03}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-04 22:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-26 01:50:00.000000', 'value': 60.34}, 'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

Instance3 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 38.12}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 42.31}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-06 07:50:00.000000', 'value': 45.22}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-04 22:50:00.000000', 'value': 40.51}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-26 01:50:00.000000', 'value': 34.35}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-11 12:50:00.000000', 'value': 46.33},'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

And many more instance details to follow ( Close to 8K instance information )
```

Question : How to advance the below coding so it can fetch from all rows of every instance  :

```
data = [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.03},{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.37}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 58.84}],'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="datapoints", meta=["metric", "unit"])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what the problem is, but if you method doesn't work for all rows, do this:

If your data looks like:

```
data = [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.03},{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.37}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 58.84}],'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

that is:

```
                                   datapoints          metric     unit
0  [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-0...  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds
```

You can define the following function:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

and apply it:

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which returns:

```
index          metric     unit datapoints.statistic  \
0      0  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds              Minimum   
0      0  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds              Minimum   
0      0  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds              Minimum   

         datapoints.timestamp  datapoints.value  
0  2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000             59.03  
0  2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000             59.37  
0  2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000             58.84
```

Comment: Follow up question related to the defined function :

Coding work fine if choose 10 line : Eg- 
Less_metric= met_data_aug.iloc[:10,:] 
flatten_nested_json_df(Less_metric) # Parsing works at all layer and extracting all columns 

If i select 1000 lines : Eg-
med_metric= met_data_aug.iloc[:1000,:] 
flatten_nested_json_df(med_metric) #  It is not parsing fully and not extracting all columns data 

Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

below code will loop through all your instance and concat them all to one big dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(instance1, record_path="datapoints", meta=["metric", "unit"])
for instance in your_remained_instances:
  df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(instance, record_path="datapoints", meta=["metric", "unit"])])
```

Comment: Any NAN values or columnar difference on instances makes the coding to break ?

How to fix this issue ?- Please guide !!

As you can it code has not de-normalized the completely .
 index metrics.metric metrics.unit metrics.datapoints
0 13445 VolumeIdleTime Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-07 18:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.98}